# AJAX request PHP only returns the first word in a string

Tags: php, ajax

I found this code from w3schools (don't judge me).

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

Its a code that lets you make a search field similar to how Google works using AJAX.

The code works fine, however in my .php the strings are more than 1 word and it only seems to output correctly if I search the first word.  If I try to put anything within a string in the input field it doesn't output.  For example, my strings might be:

```
$a[]="This is string 1."
$a[]="This is string 2."
$a[]="Is this string 3?"
$a[]="Is this string 4?"
```

The problems is that if I type 'This' it will only show the results that START with This.  If I put 'string' it will say there are no results.  Any thoughts?  I am sure the problem is in the PHP part:

```
$q=$_REQUEST["q"]; $hint="";

if ($q !== "")
{ $q=strtolower($q); $len=strlen($q);
  foreach($a as $name)
    { if (stristr($q, substr($name,0,$len)))
      { if ($hint==="")
        { $hint=$name; }
        else
        { $hint .= "<br>$name"; }
      }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or output the correct values 
echo $hint==="" ? "Refine search values" : $hint;
?>
```

Comment: That's not a problem. That's not implemented feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the documentation about `stristr()` again, especially the order of the arguments:

```
string stristr(string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = false ])
```

So your line

```
if (stristr($q, substr($name,0,$len)))
```

should actually be

```
if (stristr($name, $q))
```

As you do not use the string return by `stristr()`, it's probably better to use `stripos()`

```
if (stripos($name, $q) !== FALSE)
```

If you strings should support Unicode, replace the `str*` functions by their matching `mb_str*` functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answers to all.  I chose this one because it worked after changing that line.  Well done.

Comment: Just as an aside, how might I limit the output to, say, 20 results max?

Comment: Well, you could do a while loop that checks if that amount of `br` tags is 20 or greater and that i is smaller than the array length.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code you have does not check the entire string. Instead, your function (ww3schools actually), only looks for values in the array that begin with the same characters.

What you'll want to do is make a functionality yourself that can do a "keyword" search. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to use this function:

```
 if (strpos($str, $cont) !== FALSE)
```

Strpos checks if `$str` has a value of `$cont` and returns true if it contains that word.

Comment: That is a good idea, and I probably will do that.  For now I wanted it to search any character as the keywords are words that people at my work will already know, but I want to make a quick lookup system so it is easier to find the article(s) they need.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurring because of this line

```
substr($name, 0, $len)
```

only matching the contents of a[] from the start of the string.

Your code should be

```
if ($q !== "")
{ $q=strtolower($q); // not needed //$len=strlen($q);
  foreach($a as $name)
    { if (stristr($name, $q))
      { if ($hint==="")
        { $hint=$name; }
        else
        { $hint .= "<br>$name"; }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because of this line

$hint .="$name";

Comment: What does your suggestion fix? And could you explain how?

Comment: <?php
// Array with names
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
$a[] = "Cinderella";


// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";   *change here in your code|***
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output 
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>

Comment: An explanation would have sufficed, the code is not needed, and it's hard to read when placed in a comment.

Comment: The problem is occurring because of this line

$hint .="$name";   




<?php





$q=$_REQUEST["q"];

$hint="";





if($q!=="")





{





$q=strtolower($q);





$len=strlen($q);





foreach($a as $name)




{





if(stristr($q,substr($name,0,$len)))




{





if($hint=="")





{




$hint=$name;




}




else




{



$hint.=",$name";



}




}




}




}




echo $hint=="" ? "no suggestion":$hint; 




?>

Comment: Could you add the explanation to the answer? This will also increase the chances your answer will be up-voted, as people don't always read the comments.